# What is the proper way to add a SharedObject to a .AS file?

Tags: actionscript-3, local-shared-object

Having trouble adding a SharedObject to a .AS file, I am trying to add the users name to the .flv file in red 5 like "username_myfile" I am not sure I am adding the code thats saves the name in the correct part of the class.   is there a proper way to add a SharedObject to a .AS file?

--
added:

```
import flash.net.SharedObject;
```

---

```
package app
{
    import flash.display.BitmapData;
    import flash.display.Stage;
    import flash.external.ExternalInterface;
    **import flash.net.SharedObject;**

    public class DataHolder
    {
        private static var dataHolder:DataHolder;


        public var savedstuff:SharedObject = SharedObject.getLocal("myStuff2","/");

        if (savedstuff.size > 0)
        {
            public var username = savedstuff.data.username;

        }

             public var filename:String = (String(username) + "_myfile");

        public var rtmpPath:String = "rtmp://numbershere.compute-1.amazonaws.com/oflaDemo/";



        public var recorder:Recorder;
        public var navigation:Navigation;

        public var cameraFPS:Number = 30;
        public var cameraWidth:Number = 640;
        public var cameraHeight:Number = 480;
        public var cameraQuality:Number = 88;// camera quality

        public var timelimit:Number = 25;// limit count of seconds

        public var stage:Stage;

        public function DataHolder()
        {
            if (dataHolder)
            {
                throw new Error("Only one DataHolder instance should be instantiated");
            }
        }

        public static function getInstance():DataHolder
        {
            if (dataHolder == null)
            {
                dataHolder = new DataHolder();
            }
            return dataHolder;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code looks really weird. The if statement directly in the class definition? What is the problem even? Does it compile?

Comment: I add this and now get less errors **import flash.net.SharedObject;**

Comment: DataHolder.as, Line 14 1120: Access of undefined property savedstuff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the conditional declaration of your shared object and declare as usual, ie:

```
private var savedStuff:SharedObject;
```

Then, in your constructor:

```
try {
    savedStuff = SharedObject.getLocal("savedData");
} catch (error) {
    cookiesActive = false;
};
```

Then check cookiesActive==true to save data to the SharedObject, eg:

```
if (cookiesActive) {
    savedStuff.data.levelsFinished = 1;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried removing the '**' stars around the SharedObject import? It should be imported as normal (just like any other required classes). I should also have pointed out that you'll need to declare the boolean variable 'cookiesActive', ie; 'private var cookiesActive:Boolean'. What errors do you get? What about the code doesn't work?